# Running output of Python in html in Djngo

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I am working on a django project. In the app's views.py I am having some outputs that I am storing in a dictionary. The views.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def allblogs(request):
    a = request.GET['a']
    b = request.GET['b']

    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', {'a': a, 'b':b})
```

I am calling these a and b in the html file. When I am just showing them without any html code like this:

```
here are your {{a}} and {{b}}
```

then I am getting them in the boring white page. However, when I am trying to call them in a html code, I am getting nothing. If I try to run them like this:

```
{% a %}
```

this gives me error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/
Invalid block tag on line 98: 'a'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/?the_sender=&the_amount=
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 98: 'a'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: C:\Users\Winter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 530
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Winter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Winter\\Desktop\\portfolio-project',
 'C:\\Users\\Winter\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Winter\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Winter\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Winter\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Winter\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 11 May 2020 09:25:36 +0000
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: to show the data you just need this `here are your {{a}} and {{b}}`, the `{% %}` code is use for function like looping, including, conditional statement and so on. can you show your urls,py?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Call an arbitrary tag from a query string? I wouldn't recommend doing that, it's really insecure

Answer (score 1):

{{a}} is used whenever we are showing something as a variable from views
{% .. %} is used for conditional purposes like if we are writing for loops or if conditions or even inside some buttons we can use this as parameter to perform routing operations

Answer (score 0):

With that last error, you're mixing up tags `{% something %}` and variables `{{ something }}`.

However, if a template like

```
here are your {{a}} and {{b}}
```

works for you, there's no reason why a template like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Here's <b>{{a}}</b> and there's <i>{{b}}</i>
</body>
</html>
```

wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing something like `{% a %}`
it means that you're trying to load some tag, and your tag didn't exist, and that's the reason why you have been getting `Invalid block tag on line 98: 'a'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` error.

In order to render your context variables `a, b`

Just render them within HTML tags.

e.g

```
<p>your A context variable {{ a }} </p>
<p>your B context variable {{ b }} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your allblogs.html like given code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <p> {{a}} and {{b}} </p>
</body>
</html>
```